# detecting IE 6 using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there any way to detect IE6 through htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 6"<br>
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder/
```

But remember it's super easy to modify your User Agent